# Stack multiple icons to flutter IconButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `IconButton` and want to stack two icons to look like

[image]

I tried with `Row` layout like

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: avatarRadius,
  child: IconButton(
    icon: Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.message,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ]
    ),
    onPressed: _onAddMessageButtonClick,
  ),
),
```

But it is giving error

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 24 pixels on the right.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `IconButton` widgets

Try this

```
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 40,
          child:  GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              // perform click here
            },
            child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.message,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: The mouse cursor does not change to pointer as it does with the Button view.